# How to resolve error "listofitems.sty" not found

Tags: packages

I write my paper on **overleaf**, but when i download it and run it on **teXstudio**. texStudio open file readarray.sty and gives following error in **readarray.sty**.

`File listofitems.sty not found. \RequirePackage{listofitems}[2016-10-22]`

How can i resolve above error?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you update your distribution recently?

Comment: Sounds like you need to install [listofitems.sty](http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/CTAN/macros/generic/listofitems/).

Comment: @Andrew how can i do this

Comment: What is your distribution?

Comment: @Bernard I am new to latex, i don't know what do you mean by "distribution"

Comment: Do you use TeX Live (all platforms), MacTeX or MiKTeX (Windows)?

Comment: @Bernard i use MikTeX. For simple text of it runs fine

Comment: OK Launch MiKTeX Package Manager (Admin mode). After some time it will display the list of all available packages, indicating those already installed. Select `listofitems`, right click on it and select install.

Comment: there are no package with name of `listofitemss` , although there are package with name of `listofsymbols` and `listofanswers` @Bernard

Comment: There is, but it's a very recent package. First synchronise the repository to have the latest list (always with MPM).

Comment: @Bernard Thanks alot, after synchronising i installed it and now its working.  Add you suggestion in answer box. Once again thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Launch MiKTeX Package Manager (Admin mode). Filter the list of packages writing (part of) the name of the package in the `Name` form, right-click  on it and select `install`. You may have to ‘synchronise’ the list of packages if you want to install a recent package. This is done through the `Repository` menu in the toolbar.

If you install a font package, you also may have to run `updmap` from the command line afterwards.

[image]